# zuzüglich = hinzukommend or einschließlich?

Tags: meaning

I have a doubt concerning the meaning of the word "zuzüglich".

I know that **Duden** says: "*hinzukommend, hinzuzurechnen*", and I understand when it says "die Wohnung kostet 600 Euro zuzüglich der Heizkosten", i.e. plus heating cost. No doubt here.
But **WAHRIG Deutsches Wörterbuch** says also "*mitsamt*"
and **WAHRIG Synonymwörterbuch** means also *einschließlich* together with a couple of other dictionaries. This is already something different. It means **including**, right?

Let's take an [example](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/praepositionen/die-bedeutung-der-prapositionen-ubersicht/die-bedeutung-der-prapositionen-zuzuglich/): *Zuzüglich Mehrwertsteuer kostet das Auto 15 000 Euro.*
Explanation of it is: *(Mit)samt der Mehrwertsteuer kostet das Auto 15 000 Euro.* Which means, the total price of the car is 15.000 Euro (**including VAT**). Is that correct?

The same happens in the following [example](https://ticketist.io/terms):
*"Der Gesamtpreis zuzüglich allfälliger Gebühren wird bei jeder Bestellung angegeben. Der Gesamtpreis der Bestellung inklusive allfälliger Gebühren ist bei den Zahlarten Kreditkarte und Online Banking nach Vertragsabschluss sofort zur Zahlung fällig."* So, here by writing **zzgl.** they mean "**including**", right?

Moreover, according to the [German law](https://www.haendlerbund.de/de/ratgeber/recht/3823-preisangabenverordnung#mehrwertsteuer), if they say "Gesamtpreis" it should be the final end price for the client (Bruttopreis). So, in the last example it cannot be meant "plus", it must mean "including" as it is confirmed in the second sentence.

So I kindly ask you to confirm or disprove my thoughts.

Comment: In my opinion, "zuzüglich" does not mean "including", but that doesn't stop some people from using it that way.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the car example, I really don't know what they were thinking. This is just plain wrong.

I can easily fathom someone using this term wrongly in a longer sentence like this:

> Der Basispreis ist 12 605 Euro, und zuzüglich Mehrwertsteuer kostet das Auto dann 15 000 Euro.

So they mean that the 15 000 € is the *result* of the addition, and they express that wrongly, but it's kind of clear from the context what they mean. However, if a price is given as "XXX € zzgl. MwSt.", that clearly means that the MwSt. comes on top and is not included in XXX.

The ticketing example is actually different -- what they mean is that the shown price (angegebener Preis) does include MWSt, so it is the *Bruttopreis* that they are obliged to show by law and that will often be shown on the ticket itself, but there are still additional fees like "Vorverkaufsgebühr" (presale fee), "Systemgebühr" (system fee), "Versandgebühr" (shipping fee) etc. pp. that are shown extra, and these are only added later, that's why it says "zuzüglich allfälliger Gebühren".

As you can see, they even make the difference between "Gesamtpreis zuzüglich allfälliger Gebühren" in their first paragraph and "Gesamtpreis der Bestellung inklusive allfälliger Gebühren" in their second paragraph. These are different from each other. They only have to show the full price of your order including everything before you press the actual last button that triggers the order, often shown as "Zahlungspflichtig bestellen".

Unfortunately, this is still a common practice in some parts of the event ticketing market and related markets like flight tickets etc. EU and national lawmakers are fighting this, and some kinds of fees have to be included now, but it seems to be a constant struggle against the creativity of sellers. (I'm not an expert on the legal intricacies.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
Ok, maybe for the example with the car some more context is missing. But what about the Wahrig, Langenscheidt and some other esteemed dictionaries? Are they all together wrong?

Comment: I can't really comment on those, I don't have them. DWDS looks correct: https://www.dwds.de/wb/zuz%C3%BCglich ans does wiktionary https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zuz%C3%BCglich. My theory is that they mean certain wordings similar to the  in the car example. If you have the sentence "Der Preis zuzüglich Porto beträgt 10 €." it's actually hard to interpret even assuming the correct definition for "zuzüglich". It could be meant to mean "Der Preis (= 8 €) zuzüglich dem Porto (= 2 €) beträgt (zusammen) 10 €.", depending on whether "beträgt" is meant to already include "zuzüglich dem Porto" or not.

Comment: My suggestion for that case is: The meaning depends on the word order. I.e.: If zzgl. is after the total price, it should be translated as "plus", however if zzgl. is before the price, it should be translated as "including". What do you think?

Comment: I agree it depends on word order, but IMO, "Der Preis zuzüglich Porto beträgt 10 €." is still an ambiguous statement and could be meant either way.